# lmer model for proportion of values in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, lme4

I have a dataframe in R in which I'd like to calculate if there is a significantly higher proportion of `A`'s in the column `value` between condition X and Y.

toy dataset below:

```
subject   condition   value   proportion

1         X           A       .33
1         X           B       .33
1         Y           A       .5
1         X           C       .33
1         Y           B       .5
2         X           A       1
2         Y           A       .5
2         Y           B       .5
3         X           B       1
3         Y           A       .5
3         Y           B       .5
...
```

But I'm having trouble putting a `lmer` model together for this, since I'm comparing proportions. Does anyone have advice? Below is the code that I'm working with that is incorrect:

```
m1 <- lmer(value ~ condition + (1 + condition | subject), data = data)
summary(m1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a logistic regression. Try:

```
glmer(as.numeric(value=="A") ~ condition + (1 + condition | subject), 
         data = data, family=binomial)
```